# Inequality with numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

It seems its a simple question, but I am confused.

Let a be natural number and let b be some number $1\le b\le a$.
Find an upper bound for
$$
\frac{a^2+2b^2-4ab-a}{a(a-1)}.
$$

I've got
$$
\frac{a^2+2b^2-4ab-a}{a(a-1)}=
\frac{a+2b^2/a-4b-1}{(a-1)}\leq
3
$$
But I am not sure if its true.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $2b^2-4ab=2b^2-4ab+2a^2-2a^2=2(a-b)^2-2a^2$. (We completed the square.)  That will tell you what, given $a$, is the optimal choice for $b$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: That is exactly what I meant by given $a$, what is the optimal choice for $b$?  Wanted to leave to  student that it is $1$.

Comment: Oh, I see you changed it - the previous text with "squares are positive" would not have worked, it seems.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I initially had misread the question as asking for the *minimum*, caught it on editing.